# Visual Basic Random making buttons invisible

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I wanted to make a game that uses 16 buttons (4x4) which each button generates numbers 1, 2, and 3 in random. And when you press two buttons that contains the same number, both of them will become invisible, how would I do that? Thanks for the response.
Here is my code for the Number Generator:

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim rnd As New Random
        Button1.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button2.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button3.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button4.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button5.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button6.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button7.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button8.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button9.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button10.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button11.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button12.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button13.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button14.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button15.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
        Button16.Text = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `myButton.Visible = false; myOtherButton.Visible = false;`

Comment: Thanks for the response but is there a way that when the buttons are pressed the numbers that it contains will determine whether it will become visible or not? For example, when I pressed a button that contains "1" and I pressed another which contains "2" both of them will not disappear. But if I pressed the buttons that has the same value, both of them will disappear.

Comment: You haven't given enough detail to give a good answer. For example, if I push 1 then 2 then a third button 1, what should happen? What about 1 then 2, then 2? When you say 'contains' what do you mean? Do you have any code so far to show?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but you can only push 2 buttons at the same time, like in the game 2Fuse. The only code I have so far is the random generator. It's like a matching game actually, with a little twist.

Comment: Although it may seem like 'the same time' to the user, in your code I don't think you will get the two button click events at the same time. Your code will decide what constitutes 'the same time'...500 milliseconds or less? 1 second or less? 2?...

Comment: My bad, wrong choice of words. What I mean is when the user clicked the first button, the value will be stored then when the user clicked another button the 1st value and the 2nd value will be compared if it is the same or not. If it is the same, the buttons will disappear, when it is not nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided any code for the actual game portion you want to create, I would rather try to steer you in the right direction rather than give you the right answer. I feel like you are trying to learn rather than just get an answer.

One way to solve this issue is by defining the steps of the game.

Step 1: Create 16 buttons with randomly generated numbers. You've done this and I assume it works.

Step 2: User clicks a button and your program stores that value for later

Step 3: User clicks a second button and your program stores and compares that value to the first value

Step 4: The program either hides the buttons if numbers match or produces some confirmation that they do not match.

Step 5: The program resets to a state where it can access step 2 (edit: the program only does step one on a new game/level)

Hints: You need two variables to compare, each button will need its own function, each button will have to check if it is being clicked for the first number or second number.

If you need more help try writing some code for the actual game portion.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a huge help, i'll update you if I can make  it work. The only problem is I'm having problem on Step 5. I don't know on how to reset to a certain step and what is the logic I will use for it. :)

Comment: Oh!I forgot to tell you to I want to make at least 3 levels. When all the buttons are invisible, it will proceed to a new level where the time limit is much shorter. Sorry for the late update.

Comment: A few notes: What if you randomly generate an odd number of 1s 2s or 3s? For example if you generate 5 buttons with the number 3, there will always be one without a match. For help with step 5, think about what has changed from step 1 (think which variables changed by clicking buttons and how to get them back to an "original state"

Comment: Also, start small. Create a program with 3 buttons (2 that match and 1 that doesn't) without using random generation (you set the values manually). Then test until you get it working (the buttons that match go away, but the buttons that don't match provide a warning)

Comment: I made 4 buttons, but I still have a problem. In my game when I compare the 1st 2 buttons, and when I clicked a new button to compare, it still compare it with the last button that I clicked. I want to make it that when I clicked 2 buttons, after the comparison of their values the buttons will be un-clicked.

Comment: here is my new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934274/comparing-2-buttons-visual-basic]